# Comma operator with undeclared variable - why does it compile?

Tags: c, comma-operator

Why does this code not throw a compilation error for y being undeclared?

```
int x = 10, y;
printf("%d", y);
```

There's no expression  like `int y;`. In my case, the console print out is `32764`, which seems to just be uninitialized memory. Looking at the assembly code for the first line, it's the same whether the `, y` is there or not, even if y is used in the print statement.

Expected to see

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'    printf("%d", y);
```

Comment: Not all commas in C code are comma operators.  A comma in a declaration usually separates different 'declarators' — variable definitions.  The first line (`int x = 10, y;`) defines two variables, `x` and `y`, and initializes `x`.  For the sordid details, see [§6.7 Declarations](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) of the C standard.  Note that the commas in a function call argument list are not comma operators either, nor are the commas in the initializer list for aggregate variable types, etc.

Comment: Note: code examples such as this is the very reason why multiple declarations on a single line is considered bad and dangerous style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
int x = 10, y;
```

Is *not* an instance of the comma operator.  The `,` is part of the grammar of a declaration which allows multiple variables to be declared on the same line.  Specifically, it declares `x` and initializes it to 10 and declares `y` which is uninitialized.  It's equivalent to:

```
int x = 10;
int y;
```

Had you instead done this:

```
int x = (10, y);
```

Then you would have an instance of the comma operator and an error for an undeclared identifier.